# Is a diagnostic required for unused member templates with ill formed default template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider the following class template:

```
template<typename T>
struct S 
{    
    template<auto = T()> 
    void f();
};
```

Is it ill formed to instantiate `S` with template parameters `T`, for which `auto = T()` is ill formed?

```
int main()
{
    S<int> a;    // ok
    S<int&> b;   // error
    S<int()> c;  // gcc ok, clang error
}
```

This seems to be the case, but the issue is with `c`, where `S` is instantiated with a function type. gcc is ok with this, while clang says:

```
error: cannot create object of function type 'int ()'
```

which makes sense. Since gcc does diagnose the instantiation with `int&`, I suspect this is a gcc bug. Is that right, or is a diagnostic not required for this [code](https://godbolt.org/z/zo8fdG)?

Answer (score 1):

This is [CWG1635](http://wg21.link/cwg1635):

> **1635. How similar are template default arguments to function default arguments?**
>
> Default function arguments are instantiated only when needed. Is the same true of default template arguments? For example, is the following well-formed?
>
> ```cpp
>  #include <type_traits>
>
>  template<class T>
>  struct X {
>    template<class U = typename T::type>
>    static void foo(int){}
>    static void foo(...){}
>  };
>
>  int main(){
>    X<std::enable_if<false>>::foo(0);
>  }
> ```
>
> Also, is the effect on lookup the same? E.g.,
>
> ```cpp
>  struct S {
>    template<typename T = U> void f();
>    struct U {};
>  };
> ```
>
> **Additional note (November, 2020):**
>
> Paper P1787R6, adopted at the November, 2020 meeting, partially addresses this issue.